# Why does this recursive method return 400 instead of 404?

Tags: java, recursion

Why does the method return 400? The value "x" goes from 5, 15, 45, 135, 405, 404, 403, 402, 401, 400. I'm not sure why. Please explain.

```
public int go(int x) {
    if(x < 300)
        x = go(x * 3);
    return x - 1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, if you call it like `go(5)`, you'd get the `(x < 300)` check evaluating to true until we call it recursively with x=135 (at this point there are 4 calls of `go` on the call stack). On the next call x=135*3=405 so we get (x < 300) evaluating to false (at this point `go` is on the call stack 5 times). We then start returning and when we return, `go` is popped off of the stack. This happens 5 times (starting at x=405) decreasing x by 1 each time. Keep in mind that a recursive function completes when the first call of it is popped off of the call stack

Comment: Try running it line by line in your debugger, and at every step look at the values of the variable `x` and the call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to return different values depending on what you initially called it with.  If you initially call it with 5, it will return 400 because once it gets to 135 you're 4 layers deep into the recursive function.

So it does return 404 -- to the caller, which returns 403 to it's caller, which returns 402... until it gets to 400 at which point it is at the first caller, which is the value you're printing.

That's how recursive functions work.

Try printing the result of `go(go(go(go(go(405)))))` if that wasn't clear, because that's what you effectively have in your example when the recursion is done.